# Customer specific requirements in code base

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

How do you handle and what best practices is out there when implementing small customer specific changes in a code base?

This particular product is used by 10-20 customers and is delivered as a web application. I find it hard to manage and not clutter up the code when one customer want a specific feature that the other customers don't want or haven't bought.

I have looked at earlier code  that solves this problem with if-statements:

```
if(customerId == Customer.One) {
 // code goes here...
}
```

or

```
if(customer.hasThisSpecificFeature()) {
 // code goes here.
 }
```

The problem with this is that it's really hard to maintain when having more than a few specific features. The code is unreadable and hard to debug.

Is there a good and clean way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Further reading: [Strategy Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx); [Template Method Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternTemplate.aspx); [Inversion of Control](http://joelabrahamsson.com/inversion-of-control-an-introduction-with-examples-in-net/) (IoC).</sub>

One way of doing it is extracting the logic that has to listen to the customer specific feature and inject the implementation instead of baking it into the code.  For example, use an interface:

```
public int GetAge(Person p)
{
    return p.Age;
}
```

A customer wants to lie about the ages, so asks you to add 1 to all ages:

```
public int GetAge(Person p)
{
    var age = p.Age;

    // Imagine all this exists...
    if (CustomerContext.CurrentCustomer == Customer.One)
    {
        age++;
    }

    return age;
}
```

The idea would be to extract the post processing of age:

```
public int GetAge(Person p, IAgePostProcessor ageProcessor)
{
    var age = p.Age;
    return ageProcessor.Process(age);
}

public interface IAgePostProcessor
{
    int Process(int age);
}
```

Then outside of this you can decide to configure strategies once at start up when you know what customer context you are in.

For that one customer, you provide an implementation that +1s the age, for everyone else you provide a pass-through implementation that does nothing.

You can utilise other DI/IoC frameworks (Ninject, Castle Windsor, StructureMap) to help with the plumbing for this stuff.

---

Alternatively, your "interface" could simply be a `Func<int, int>`:

```
public int GetAge(Person p, Func<int, int> postProcessAge)
{ 
    if (postProcessAge == null)
        postProcessAge = a => a; // Do nothing.

    return postProcessAge(p.Age);
}
```

This again moves the dependency outside of this method and allows you to make the decision on logic elsewhere, perhaps centralised once at start up.

---

The benefit with all approaches is that you can test customer-specific implementations independently of where they are used to prove acceptance criteria is met for each client.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that developers should **stay away customer specific code**.

IF you are allowing customizations to your product you should **abstract the customization** out enough so that any client can change "settings" of the customization/feature for their specific install. Even if the feature is completely new, this will add a new feature to your product and you want to allow any of your customers the same benefit.

The **settings for these customization should be contained in a config file or database table**. This allows any customer to use the feature you are building and allow each customer to change the setting to their requirements without requiring changes to code and redeployment.

It may cause a little more work ahead of time, but keeps your code base from getting cluttered up with each customers customization and makes tweaks/adjustments to the feature a lot easier.